# Vertical output XSL and XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I am working on a simple dictionary in XML, and now I'm trying to output some words vertical, but they all come out on a line without spaces.

This is some of the XML file

```
<thesaurus>
  <dictionary>
    <language>English</language>
    <word type="1">word 1</word>
    <word type="2">word 2</word>
    <word type="3">word 3</word>
    <word type="4">word 4</word>
    <word type="5">word 5</word>
    <word type="6">word 6</word>
    </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

This is my first "almost" solution

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="//word">

          <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That solution only prints out all the word like this

> AgentsColorFoundationsGrainPartialPogotypePretendSilentStrollTender

My second try is something like this

```
 <xsl:for-each select="thesaurus">
         <h1> <xsl:value-of select="//word"/></h1>
               </xsl:for-each>
```

In that way I could style the words and they will print vertical, but the thing is that only the first of the words is printing. =/

Would be great with a hint :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/word">
          <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <body>word 1<br />word 2<br />word 3<br />word 4<br />word 5<br />word 6<br /></body>
</html>
```